# How to search through a gallery of photos containing QR Codes for a character string

Tags: php, mysql, qr-code

I have a folder of images, each containing a QR Code within the picture which acts as a unique identifier for that image. Each QR Code represents an "Order Number" in the form of "SO12345"

What would be great is if I could just upload these photos to something like dropbox, and then type an order number into the search box and find the image that contains the QR Code equivalent of that search phrase.

Is there an existing service that can do this? Or would it have to be custom written? Is there a PHP library I could use?

Assuming it has to be done using a PHP library, there are 2 ways I could see doing this.

1. Each time you search for a character phrase, it has to loop through each image 1 by 1 till it either completes with no matches, or finds a match, this format would take longer and longer as the directory increases in size.

Or

2. Have a function loop through every image as they are uploaded, and if it finds a QR Code, it decodes it and either changes the file name to the QR Code value, or it updates a MySQL row table to associate the QR Code value with the file name. Then the search function searches for a match in file name, or a match in MySQL row value.

Ideally I would rather not reinvent the wheel if necessary. But if it has to be done I would appreciate any help you can offer on where to start to accomplish this.

Comment: You should probably have metadata information about the QR code saved in your database.

Comment: im sorry you lost me a little bit, could you explain a little further?

Comment: Read the QR code and put the contents into a database field so that it's searchable.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload the photos to google drive and just name the pictures the QR code. Then just search the QR code in the google drive and it should come up.

Comment: sorry i should have specified, the whole purpose of having the QR Code visible in the photo is to find it later via a search. These photos are being batch uploaded by the hundreds so renaming each one wont work. They are automatically being uploaded from a wifi digital camera to the webstorage as they are taken. so finding the photo you want later is the goal